# A confusion about the norm of the restriction of a linear mapping.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $\Bbb X$ be a Banach space, $T:\Bbb X\to \Bbb X$ be a linear map and $P:\Bbb X\to \Bbb X$ be a projection operator. Denote the closed subspace that is the range of $P$ by $\Bbb Y:=\mathcal R(P)$. Suppose that $||P||\le M$.

I was reading an article and there's a line claiming that
$$
\lVert T|_{\Bbb Y}\rVert\le M\lVert T\rVert
$$ 
with no further explaination. A first I was confused since normally we'd only have
$$
\lVert T|_{\Bbb V}\rVert\le \lVert T\rVert
$$ 
whenever $\Bbb V$ is a subspace of $\Bbb X$ but then I realized that it is possible that $T|_{\Bbb Y}$ can be view as $T|_{\Bbb Y}:(\Bbb Y,\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\Bbb Y})\to (\Bbb X,\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\Bbb X})$ where $\Bbb Y$ is endowed with a different norm from $\Bbb X$ and, similarly, $P$ is $P:(\Bbb X,\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\Bbb X})\to (\Bbb Y,\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\Bbb Y})$. If this is the case then we could have

$$\begin{align}
\lVert T|_{\Bbb Y}\rVert &:=\sup_{||x||_{\Bbb Y}\le 1}|T(x)| \\
&\le \sup_{||x||_{\Bbb X}\le M}|T(x)| \\
&=  \sup_{||x||_{\Bbb X}\le 1}|T(Mx)| \\
&= M\lVert T\rVert\ .
\end{align}$$

My problem is that I am not quite sure if this is what the author intended or not. Is there any plausible reason that one would want a different norm on $\Bbb Y$? Is there a flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: Seems a little bit weird, are you sure $P$ is meant to be a projection? In which case $\Vert P\Vert=1$...

Comment: @Mandrathax Yes, $P$ is a projection in general, not necessary an orthogonal projection.

Comment: Om sorry if I'm mistaken, it's been some times since I've done this but... isn't a projector defined by $P^2=P$? Hence $P$ has norm 1 as it is it's biggest eigenvalue, regardless of its orthogonality or not. Unless you're not talking about the induced norm in which case you should probably mention it.

Comment: @Mandrathax You could consider 
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}\ ,$$
a projection from $\Bbb R^2$ onto $\Bbb R$. I believe it's norm should be $\sqrt 2$ and is attain by the vector $(0.5,0.5)$. Its eigenvalues are indeed $1$ and $0$.

Comment: @Mandrathax The largest eigenvalue controls the ($L^2$-induced) norm for a *symmetric* matrix, but a non-orthogonal projection matrix won't be symmetric.  For general matrices it's actually the largest singular value that counts.

Comment: OK thank you all, good to have my memory refreshed, sorry for the dumb question then ;)